# Need a join query for data

Tags: mysql

I have below tables

A) product_free_issue

```
pfi_id  pfi_lo_id
14966    57
```

B) product_free_issue_detail

```
pfd_id pfd_pfi_id pfd_pr_price
30158  14966         677.97
30157  14966         677.97
```

C) product_free_issue_audit

```
pa_id pa_pfi_id pa_issue_qty  pa_missing_extra
3421  14966      2                  +8
3420  14966      3                  +7
```

Here the primary key **pfi_id** of tabel **product_free_issue** is foreign key in **product_free_issue_detail** and **product_free_issue_audit tabels**

Need a join query that reproduce data like -

```
pfi_id  pfi_lo_id pfd_id pfd_pfi_id pfd_pr_price pa_id pa_pfi_id pa_issue_qty  pa_missing_extra
14966    57        30158  14966         677.97     3421  14966      2                  +8
14966    57        30157  14966         677.97     3420  14966      3                  +7
```

I have tried this query (1)

```
SELECT pfi.*,pfd.*,pa.*
FROM (`product_free_issue` as pfi)
INNER JOIN `product_free_issue_detail` as pfd ON `pfd`.`pfd_pfi_id` = `pfi`.`pfi_id`
INNER JOIN `product_free_issue_audit` as pa ON `pa_pfi_id` = `pfi`.`pfi_id`
WHERE 
`pa`.`pa_lo_id` =  '57'    
 GROUP BY `pfd_id`
```

They returns data like

```
   pfi_id   pfi_lo_id  pfd_id  pfd_pfi_id   pfd_pr_price   pa_id     pa_pfi_id  pa_issue_qty    pa_missing_extra 
14996   57         30157    14996           677.97      3420      14996         3               +7
14996   57         30158    14996           677.97      3420      14996         3               +7
```

and this one (2)

```
SELECT pfi.*,pfd.*,pa.*
FROM (`product_free_issue` as pfi)
INNER JOIN `product_free_issue_detail` as pfd ON `pfd`.`pfd_pfi_id` = `pfi`.`pfi_id`
INNER JOIN `product_free_issue_audit` as pa ON `pa_pfi_id` = `pfi`.`pfi_id`
WHERE 
`pa`.`pa_lo_id` =  '57'    
 GROUP BY `pa_id`
```

Then returns data like

```
pfi_id  pfi_lo_id   pfd_id  pfd_pfi_id  pfd_pr_price    pa_id   pa_pfi_id   pa_issue_qty    pa_missing_extra    
14996   57          30157   14996           677.97           3420    14996              3               +7
14996   57          30157   14996           677.97           3421    14996              2               +8
```

Comment: If  you want to join the tables, say product_free_issue and product_free_issue_detail, the pfi_id 14966    should be there in both. If the keys are different, then there is no point in joining them

Comment: Somehow you confused IDs in your sample data. Please check `pfd_pfi_id` and `pa_pfi_id`. You only have 14966 there, but in your result you combine 14966 with 14988. I don't think this is desired.

Comment: Moreover: do you really want `pfd_id` and `pa_id` in your results? They don't seem to be directly related. If `pfi_id` 14999 has the two `pfd_id` 1 and 2, and the two `pa_id` 3 and 4, then you'd already produce four result rows: 14999/1/3, 14999/1/4, 14999/2/3, 14999/2/4.

Comment: I have edited your post to show the queries as code, which makes it more readable, one more vote is needed to reopen your post :)

Comment: This is just example of my table because the actual table have many columns.Yes i also want pfd_id and pa_id . Yes table have many entry like 14988 but i am explaining here for 14966 only to get result above like.

Comment: Okay, you want a partial cross join of pfd and pa. This is a strange requirement, but okay. But your second result row shows pfi_id 14988 with pfd_pfi_id 14996 and pa_pfi_id 14996. By what rule shall these be combined? (I still think there are typos.)

Comment: Sorry, I just update my code please check now.

Comment: Okay. Can you please explain why you join pfd_id 30158 with pa_id 3421 and not with 3420? And why you join pfd_id 30157 with pa_id 3420 and not with 3421? What is the rule you are applying here? I don't see the connnection of one particular pfd_id to one pa_id (which is why I thought you want to cross join and get four instead of two rows). Please explain.

Comment: Yes,This is the actual problem some previous developer missed this connection of pfd_id in pa_id, we have only one common key pfi_id on both table.So need data base on it.

Comment: So you think that pfd records and pa records should be related? A `product_free_issue_audit` is actually an audit on a `product_free_issue_detail` and not on a mere `product_free_issue`? How do you know that pa_id 3421 belongs to pfd_id 30158 and not to pfd_id 30157? I have no clue how you make this connection.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT pfi.pfi_id,
       pfi.pfi_lo_id,
       pfid.pfd_id,
       pfid.pfd_pfi_id,
       pfid.pfd_pr_price,
       pfia.pa_id,
       pfia.pa_pfi_id,
       pfia.pa_issue_qty,
       pfia.pa_missing_extra
FROM product_free_issue pfi
INNER JOIN product_free_issue_detail pfid
ON pfi.pfi_id=pfid.pfd_pfi_id
INNER JOIN product_free_issue_audit pfia
ON pfi.pfi_id=pfia.pa_pfi_id
```

Comment: This is return 4 records repeat data multiple times.BUt I need only 2 records for above example.